# How to hide soft navigation keys (android)

Tags: c, android-ndk

I am using native app glue to make an android app entirely in C. There is no java in this app at all. I am trying to find a way to hide the soft input keys, and I have tried

```
ANativeActivity_hideSoftInput(app->activity, ANATIVEACTIVITY_HIDE_SOFT_INPUT_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

and

```
ANativeActivity_hideSoftInput(app->activity, ANATIVEACTIVITY_HIDE_SOFT_INPUT_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

with no luck. I have also tried putting this into my android manifest:

```
<activity 
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" 
...
```

or

```
<activity
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
...
```

with no luck. Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: windowSoftInputMode is related to the keyboard. You should use `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` instead.

Comment: Where would that go?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, any luck?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but I've recently had the same problem.  The implementations below were found in this conversation: https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/674511-auto-hide-nav-bar-on-android-app-ndk/

To hide the nav bar at the top you need to add this line to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`

You can add it like this

```
        <activity android:name="android.app.NativeActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

To hide the nav bar at the bottom you need to write the following code.

```
void AutoHideNavBar(struct android_app* state)
{
    JNIEnv* env;
    state->activity->vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);

    jclass activityClass = env->FindClass("android/app/NativeActivity");
    jmethodID getWindow = env->GetMethodID(activityClass, "getWindow", "()Landroid/view/Window;");

    jclass windowClass = env->FindClass("android/view/Window");
    jmethodID getDecorView = env->GetMethodID(windowClass, "getDecorView", "()Landroid/view/View;");

    jclass viewClass = env->FindClass("android/view/View");
    jmethodID setSystemUiVisibility = env->GetMethodID(viewClass, "setSystemUiVisibility", "(I)V");

    jobject window = env->CallObjectMethod(state->activity->clazz, getWindow);

    jobject decorView = env->CallObjectMethod(window, getDecorView);

    jfieldID flagFullscreenID = env->GetStaticFieldID(viewClass, "SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN", "I");
    jfieldID flagHideNavigationID = env->GetStaticFieldID(viewClass, "SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION", "I");

    int flagFullscreen = env->GetStaticIntField(viewClass, flagFullscreenID);
    int flagHideNavigation = env->GetStaticIntField(viewClass, flagHideNavigationID);

    int flag = flagFullscreen | flagHideNavigation;

    env->CallVoidMethod(decorView, setSystemUiVisibility, flag);

    state->activity->vm->DetachCurrentThread();
}
```